# Proving this is a covering map

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a region in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, and $f\in H(\Omega)$ be a non-constant holomorphic function in $\Omega$. Let $z_0\in \Omega$ and define $w_0=f(z_o)$.

Then I know (from theorem) that there exists an open neighbourhood $V$ of $z_0$ and a holomorphic function $\phi \in H(V)$ such that

$$f(z)=w_0 + [\phi(z)]^m~~~~~~~~~~\forall z \in V$$

it follows that $f(z)$ is an $m$ to $1$ mapping of $V-\{z_0\}$ to $D(w_0,r)-\{w_0\}$ for some $r \gt 0$.

Then how do I prove $f$ is an $m-$fold covering map? ($m-$fold part is clear as it is an $m$ to 1 mapping)

Comment: $f$ is not a covering map in general. It is a branched covering.

Comment: I guess $V-\{z_0\} \to D(w_0,r)-\{w_0\}$ instead of $V \to D(w_0,r)$ makes it into a covering map.

Comment: Oh, yes. From (theorem) you should also get that $\phi$ has $\phi' \neq 0$ for all $x\in V$. Then $f$ is more or less like $z\mapsto z^m$.